# Receiving ALL props in a child component

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to receive ALL props passed in a child component without explicitly specifying them one by one? Eg:

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return <ChildComponent 
     prop1={"foo"}
     prop2={"bar"}
     prop3={"baz"}
  />
}

const ChildComponent = (props) => {
  return <input /*GIMME ALL PROPS HERE*/ />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the spread operator for this -

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return <input {...props} />
}
```

This gets automatically interpreted as -

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return <input prop1={"foo"}
                  prop2={"bar"}
                  prop3={"baz"} />
}
```